# Closed form for $\left(-1\right)^{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\left(-1\right)^{k}\binom{n}{k}2^{\binom{k}{2}}$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, closed-form, inclusion-exclusion

Given $n$ cities, we need to construct a path passing through all the cities, in how many ways it can be done?

---

Label the cities and define:

$$A_i:=\left\{\text{Paths passing through the $i$th city}\right\}$$

Between any two of the cities either there is a way or there is not, so we can choose $2$ of the $n$ places and then decide to construct a path between them or not, it can be done in $2^{\binom{n}{2}}$ ways.

The desired result is given by:

$$\left|\bigcap _{i=1}^nA_{i}\right|$$$$=2^{\binom{n}{2}}-\binom{n}{1}2^{\binom{n-1}{2}}+\binom{n}{2}2^{\binom{n-2}{2}}-...+(-1)^{n-1}\binom{n}{n-1}2^{\binom{n-(n-1)}{2}}+(-1)^{n}\binom{n}{n}2^{\binom{n-n}{2}}$$$$=2^{\binom{n}{2}}+\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(-1\right)^{k}\binom{n}{k}2^{\binom{n-k}{2}}$$$$=\left(-1\right)^{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\left(-1\right)^{k}\binom{n}{k}2^{\binom{k}{2}}$$$$=a(n)$$

I could not find any closed form for the summation, It would be highly appreciated if someone gives me a closed form (if it does exist) or help me to simplify it (if it can be simpler).

Comment: There is no known closed form (else the OEIS would list it), and the summation is a simple as it gets.

Comment: I don't follow your inclusion-exclusion argument, but isn't the number of such paths just $n!$?

Answer (score 1):

There is no closed form for $a_n$.

However, it seems that
$$\log(a_n) \sim C x^2 \qquad \text{with} \qquad C \sim 0.34614$$ This results from a quick and dirty regression for $3 \leq n \leq 1000$ $(a_{1000} \sim 3.04 \times 10^{150364})$.

The constant $C$ was not recognized by inverse symbolic calculators but it looks like $\frac 12 \log(2)$.

Notice that, in the $OEIS$ page, Vaclav Kotesovec proposed
$$a_n \sim 2^{\frac{n(n-1)}{2} }$$ which is in a relative arror of $1$% if $n>11$, $0.1$% if $n>15$, $0.01$% if $n >18$

Answer (score 0):

Inclusion-exclusion works for things like $\displaystyle \left | \bigcup _{i=1}^nA_i\right |$ but you are seemed to be interested in $\left |\displaystyle \bigcap _{i=1}^n A_i\right |.$ If you want to count the number of paths in which you pass just once in each city then you just want to put an order in the path, so a total ordering in $n$ vertices can be done in $n!$ as proposed by **RobPratt** in the comments.
What you are doing is to choose some set of edges and you take out the choices that exclude **at least** one vertex. This is exactly edge coverings of the complete graph. Notice that in your options, it might be the following choice: You fix a city and then construct n paths, one to go from the chosen city to each other city. 
What you are actually computing is $$\left |\text{All edge choices}\setminus \bigcup _{i=1}^n A_i\right |,$$ where $A_i=\{\text{edge choices that do not touch $i-$th city }\}.$

Comment: Still, then, $A_i$ should be defined as in the second part of the text above. As defined there, the inclusion-exclusion makes no sense.